# How to send application/json data along with file in postman multipart/form-data post request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, postman

My requirement is something like this. I have a DTO class as below

```
public class Employee{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String designation;
    private byte[] employeeImage;
}
```

My API is below,

```
@PostMapping(value="/createEmployees")
            public ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeDTO>> createEmployees(@RequestParam("id") Long id, 
                    @RequestBody List<EmployeeDTO> employeeList){
}
```

I am trying to send a request using postman, but the image isn't getting saved. Below is my postman request.

[image: Postman Request]

Everything is fine, but image isn't getting saved.

Anyhelp is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending Base 64 encoded image, then also decode it some thing like this :

```
        //This will decode the String which is encoded by using Base64 class
        byte[] imageByte=Base64.decodeBase64(imageByteValue);

        String directory=servletContext.getRealPath("/")+"images/sample.jpg";

        new FileOutputStream(directory).write(imageByte);
        return "success ";
```

You should take your image from Employee DTO and decode it to save at its respective directory.